# TypeError: can't concat str to bytes (I can see this as error)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, automation

all this is my part of code,

```
scr1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/ul/div/li[%s]' % i)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", scr1)
sleep(1)
text = scr1.text
list = text.encode('utf-8').split()
dirname = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
csvfilename = os.path.join(dirname, account + "-" + page + ".txt")
file_exists = os.path.isfile(csvfilename)
f = open(csvfilename, 'a')
f.write(list[0] + '\rb\n')
f.close()
print('{};{}'.format(i, list[0]))
if i == (count - 1):
    print(x)
```

So currently when I run this part of code, I get the below error,

```
   f.write(list[0] + '\r\n')
TypeError: can't concat str to bytes
```

Can anyone help me like what am I supposed to change?
Thank you and I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Why are you encoding the string to bytes in the first place — `text.encode('utf-8')`?

Comment: Removed it and it works fine. Ty @MarkMeyer

Answer (score 0):

It's because the return type of the encode() function is an array of bytes. For example:

```
'ábc'.encode('UTF-8')
```

Produces *b'\xc3\xa1bc'*.

Try:

```
f.write(list[0])
f.write('\rb\n')
```